# Why does the following equation sometimes describe a circle and sometimes a line?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

From page $19$ of Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis*:

"[...] this equation takes the form [...]

$$(\alpha_0-\alpha_3)(x^2+y^2)-2\alpha_1x-2\alpha_2y+\alpha_0+\alpha_3 = 0.$$

For $\alpha_0\ne \alpha_3$ this is the equation of a cricle, and for $\alpha_0=\alpha_3$ it is the equation of a straight line."

**Why does the equation above describe a circle whenever $\alpha_0\ne\alpha_3$ and a line otherwise?**

---

If asked to write (a set of) equations for a circle or a straight line I would either write them as parametrizations or as intersections of a plane and a sphere, or of two planes respectively, yet the equation above does not seem to take any of these forms.

Comment: "For $\alpha_0=\alpha_3$ it is the equation of a straight line" *except if $\alpha_2=0.$* "For $\alpha_0\ne \alpha_3$ this is the equation of a c*ir*cle" *or $\varnothing.$*

Comment: Is obvious why the equation is linear if $\alpha_0=\alpha_3: y=\frac{\alpha_1-\alpha_0}{\alpha_2}, \alpha_2\ne 0$. This is a horizontal line. As for why it could represent the equation of a circle: because it could be rewritten as $x^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$, if the remaining free terms add to (a positive) $r^2$.

Comment: A line is just a circle with its center at infinity.

Comment: " I would either write them as parametrizations or as intersections of a plane and a sphere, or of two planes respectively": ? you are in 2D, not in 3D.

Comment: When $\alpha_0=\alpha_3$ the equation becomes
$$-2\alpha_1x-2\alpha_2y+2\alpha_3= 0\Leftrightarrow \alpha_1x+\alpha_2y=\alpha_3, \alpha_1\ne 0 \text { or }\alpha_2\ne 0:\text{ the equation of a line}$$

Comment: When $\alpha_0\ne\alpha_3$ the equation becomes

$$x^2-2x\cdot \frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_0-\alpha_3}+\left(\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_0-\alpha_3}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_0-\alpha_3}\right)^2 + y^2-2y\cdot \frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_0-\alpha_3}+\left(\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_0-\alpha_3}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_0-\alpha_3}\right)^2 +\frac{\alpha_0+\alpha_3}{\alpha_0-\alpha_3}=0$$

Comment: $$\Leftrightarrow \underbrace{\left(x-\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_0-\alpha_3}\right)^2}_{(x-x_0)^2}+ \underbrace{\left(y-\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_0-\alpha_3}\right)^2}_{(y-y_0)^2}= \underbrace{\left(\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_0-\alpha_3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_0-\alpha_3}\right)^2 -
\frac{\alpha_0+\alpha_3}{\alpha_0-\alpha_3}}_{r^2}$$

Comment: As long as $\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2+\alpha_3^2\gt \alpha_0^2$ then the right side of equal is a positive number, this is the equation of a circle of radius r and with the center in $(x_0,y_0)$.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that there's an $x$ missing in your equation (possibly a misprint in the book)

From basic analytic geometry an equation
$$
x^2+y^2-2ax-2by+c=0\qquad(\ast)
$$
describes a circle of centre $(a,b)$ and radius $r$ with $r^2=a^2+b^2-c$.

If $\alpha_0\neq\alpha_3$ the given equation reduces to $(\ast)$ dividing by a scalar.

If $\alpha_0=\alpha_3$ the quadratic term disappears and you are left with a linear equation which describes a line **unless the linear terms disappear as well**.

Comment: The equation of your "circle of centre $(a,b)$ and radius $r$ with $r^2=a^2+b^2-c$" is not $(*).$

Comment: While you point out the probably missing $x$ in the original, you left out the $y$ in the other term.

Comment: A $y$ dropped out from your equation $(*).$

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: LOL, I fixed it. Apparently mistyping is contagious. Wonder about the negative, though.